# Gulp location of unhandled error in events.js:141

Tags: javascript, debugging, gulp, traceback

When I run task for example using comman `gulp scripts:common`, I get this output:

```
[14:05:47] Requiring external module babel-core/register
[14:05:49] Using gulpfile /home/sites/blablabla/gulpfile.babel.js
[14:05:49] Starting 'scripts:common'...

events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token
```

Well, for SyntaxError it would be useful to know where it found that unexpected token. How to tell it to show at least file and line? Where to find that evetns.js file? Could I put `console.trace()` or something like that there?

Comment: Please, post contents of gulp's scripts:common task and the output of gulp command with -v flag (verbose mode).

Answer (score 1):

I solve this problem by running [`jshint`](http://jshint.com/) on my scripts:

```
/*
 * `gulp check_scripts` - Lints script files
 */
gulp.task('check_scripts', function() {
  return gulp.src([
    'gulpfile.js' //, other scripts to check
  ])
  .pipe(jshint())
  .pipe(jshint.reporter('jshint-stylish'))
  .pipe(gulpif(enabled.failJSHint, jshint.reporter('fail')));
});
```

`enabled.failJSHint` is there to allow errors to pass in local environment but fail in production.

This will lint any syntax errors in your scripts.
Additionally you may want to hook it to other task so it's run automatically before proper build:

```
gulp.task('default', ['check_scripts', 'clean'], function() {
  gulp.start('build');
});
```

This is the general idea.

Comment: Could this bug happen only with javascript scripts, or could scss also be blamed for such error?

Comment: Gulp shouldn't crash, no. By default, it will log errors to console, which can be ignored or not, depending on your setup.

Comment: It does not crash, It just fails build on staging and I'm not able to figure out why. The problem is there is near 15 tasks there, and I'm even don't know which of them to blame.

Comment: Can you post your `gulpfile.js` then?

Comment: It contains 8 imports and looks like this: `gulp.task(':debug', cb => seq('clean', [
    'assets',
    'assets:fonts',
    'markup:pages',
    'markup:components',
    'scripts:vendor',
    'scripts:common',
    'scripts:debug',
    'styles:vendor',
    'styles:debug'
  ],
  'markup', cb));` Not think that would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can look at error stack trace by adding custom "on error" handler to the gulp task.

```
gulp.task('compile:js', function() {
    return (
        gulp.src(jsPath)
        .pipe(yourCustomTask())
        .on('error', function(err) {
            console.log(err.stack);
            this.end();
        })
    );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, as another variant, adding [gulp-plumber](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-plumber) into pipeline makes error messages more clear.